# Deploying database along with clickone application does not attached DB itself

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have a SQL Server Express based database deployment. I created a clickone application with prerequisites like SQL Server 2008. When I install my clickone my application gets installed properly without any errors, but while starting the application, it gives me error that my application is unable to find database at `C:\Users\Xnor\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\N24R9574.9H1\V0Q1MX0C.0X9\....`

I surfed stackoverflow and found that copying my `.mdf` to this location will fix my problem. But why is this happening. Why not it copies itself?

Isn't there any way to attach the DB permanently to my application, so that i can avoid this manual work?

Everywhere its just instructions to copy `.mdf` file to that location and that's it. So is there any way that could work, maybe if it is possible and suggestible that `.mdf` would be attached in resources and could be used from there. Looking for expert advice, the best way to accomplish it.

Comment: I used a sqlite database for my clickonce application, you can store the database in the appdata folder, so it doesn't get removed when updating the application, it is also very easy to use.

Comment: @Mobstaa But i am forced to use SQL Server Express because of the client server features of the application.